# Prove convergence in distribution of $T_{n}=\frac{\sqrt n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}}$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Being $X_{1},X_{2},..X_{n}$ independent random variables distributed $N(0,1)$

Being $T_{n}=\frac{\sqrt n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}}$ that converges in distribution to $T$. Find $T$.

I know that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{n} \rightarrow \mu$ (in probability)

Also, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}^{2}}{n} \rightarrow \mu^{2}+\sigma^{2}$

( Weak law of large numbers) $\rightarrow$ $E X^{2}=V(X)+[EX]^{2}=\sigma^{2}+\mu^{2}$

I think I must Slutsky theorem to solve this. But I don´t know how.

Comment: What is the $i$ in $X_i$ on the bottom?

Comment: Is your denominator actually $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$T_{n}=\frac{\sqrt n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}}= (\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}/\sqrt n) \frac 1  {{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2}}/n}$. By CLT  the first factor converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$. By Strong Law the second factor converges with probability $1$ to $1$. Hence, $T_n$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

EDIT: As pointed out by Sangachul Lee, CLT theorem is not required since the first factor has $N(0,1)$ distribution for each $n$.

Comment: (+1) The situation is much better in OP's case, since we actually have $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1) $$ for each $n$ under the OP's setting.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for the answers!